# Swift IAP localized price

Tags: swift, ios8, in-app-purchase

I am trying to add localised prices via labels to my shop section of my game. I am struggling to get it to work.

This is 1 part of the code for the purchase bit, its pretty standard.

I have an enum for all my product identifiers.

```
enum ProductID: String {
   case product1
   case product2
}
```

and the standard payment code.

```
func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, updatedTransactions transactions: [AnyObject]!) {
println("add payment")

    for transaction in transactions {

     switch transaction.transactionState {

    case .purchased:
        print("buy, ok unlock iap here")
        print(p.productIdentifier)

        let productIdentifier = transaction.payment.productIdentifier

        switch productIdentifier {
        case ProductID.product1.rawValue:
            print("Product 1 bought")
            //do something
        case ProductID.product2.rawValue:
           print("Product 2 bought")
           //do something
         default:
             print("IAP not setup")
     }
 }
```

I use the following extension for fetching the localized price, again pretty boiler plate

```
extension SKProduct {

    var localizedPrice: String {
        let formatter = NSNumberFormatter() 
        formatter.numberStyle = .CurrencyStyle
        formatter.locale = self.priceLocale
        return formatter.stringFromNumber(self.price) ?? "\(price)"
    }
}
```

So in my price labels that are underneath product buttons how do i got about adding each products localised price

```
priceProduct1Label.text = "\(?.localizedPrice)"
priceProduct2Label.text = "\(?.localizedPrice)"
```

What do I type for the question marks basically?. The videos and tutorial I read either don't tell you or they don't use a switch statement for the products. 
Thank you very much in advance for any replies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out finally. I basically took the same code that is used to identify a product when one of the buy buttons is pressed. I just replaced the line that loads the buyProduct() function with the label details. Such as this example of one of my price labels.

```
func loadPriceLabel1() {
    for product in products where product.productIdentifier == ProductID.product1.rawValue {

       self.titleLabel.text = "\(product.localizedTitle)"
       self.priceLabel1.text = "\(product.localizedPrice)"
       etc        
    }
}
```

I load the label functions after the product request is finished, right after the buy buttons become enabled. Probably a solution slightly on the clunky side but it works great. If anyone has any suggestions for improvements please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

I offer a slight variation on crashoverride777's answer above for, rather than a label, a button, and to draw not only the localized price from iTunes Connect but also the other content - the localizedTitle - that makes up the button title:

```
    func loadBuy00ButtonTitle() {
    for product in productArray {
        let prodID = product.productIdentifier
        if(prodID == "com.YourCompanyNameGoesHere.YourAppNameGoesHere.buy00Button") {
            let prod = product
            buy00Button.setTitle("Buy \(prod.localizedTitle): \(prod.localizedPrice())", for: .normal)
        }
    }
}
```

I'm in the USA and thus my button title reads something like: "Buy 100 coins: $0.99" - where for that product (purchase) "100 coins" is the localized title and "$0.99" is the localized price.

And again with minor variations, I, too, use the same extension he provides (in his question), which I place in a separate Swift file:

```
import StoreKit

extension SKProduct {

    func localizedPrice() -> String {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .currency
        formatter.locale = self.priceLocale
        return formatter.string(from: self.price)!
    }

}
```

[Ben Dodson's SKProduct localized price extension in Swift](https://bendodson.com/weblog/2014/12/10/skproduct-localized-price-in-swift/)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for an instance of `SKProduct`, of which you can load using one or more product identifiers through an `SKProductsRequest`:

```
import StoreKit

class MyStore: NSObject, SKProductsRequestDelegate {

    func loadProductsForProductIdentifiers( productIdentifiers: Set<String ) {

        let productRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productIdentifiers )
        productRequest.delegate = self ///< Make sure to set a delegate
        productRequest.start()
    }

    // MARK: - SKProductsRequestDelegate

    func productsRequest(request: SKProductsRequest!, didReceiveResponse response: SKProductsResponse!) {

        for object in response.products {
            if let product = object as? SKProduct {
                // Store these products and use their `productIdentifier` property to identify them
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I used these 2 tutorials which are basically the same (https://www.airpair.com/ios/posts/swift-storekit-in-app-purchases), (http://www.seemuapps.com/tutorial-swift-in-app-purchases). All my purchases are working perfect. I just don't understand how to fetch the price for an individual item to show it in my label called price 1. So i am looking for the right way to write "self.priceLabel1".text = "\(Product1.localizedPrice())". What do i write for product 1 basically, i tried the NSSet of ProductIDs etc but no luck.  Thanks again, I appreciate your help

Comment: Check my comment, I change it. I am already requesting the products etc and its fetching the info so I am not sure what you mean exactly. I am making a SpriteKit game where I have 5 product buttons with 5 price labels underneath. I just don't understand how to write the code for those 5 labels to get the correct price for each of them.

Comment: If you have a reference to the product already, why not just `self.priceLabel.text = product1.localizedPrice()`?

Comment: sorry I think I am not explaining probably. The product1 thing was me just trying to say that I don't know what goes in there basically. I uses this for loading the products                      if(SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()) {
            println("IAP IS ENABLED, LOADING")
            var productID = NSSet(objects: "PRODUCT IDS HERE")
            var request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID as Set<NSObject>)
            request.delegate = self
            request.start()

Comment: So as you can see its basically a NSSet of the products iDS, 5 in my case. I just don't understand how to grab one of them basically and put it in my label statement of "self.price1Label = "\( ? .localizedPrice)". They are not defined individually but as "var list = [SKProduct]() // array of products" and
    "var prod = SKProduct() //single prod". Exactly like the SeemuApps video basically. I wonder if thats the issue